# How can I sort documents using Mongoose.js 3.8.20 and MongoDB 2.6.5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Sorting documents using Mongoose 3.8.20 doesn't work with MongoDB 2.6.5. With previous versions of MongoDB I was able to use `.sort({ orgName: 'ASC' })` without a problem, now it causes an error.

```js
database.model.clients.find({ myField: 'value' })
.sort({ orgName: 'ASC' })  // Error: { [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification] name: 'MongoError' }
.sort({ orgName: 1 })      // Sorting is ignored.
.sort('orgName')           // Sorting is ignored.
.exec(function (err, docs) {
  
  console.log(err);  
  
});
```

How can I sort the documents?

Comment: In the first  case you should use asc no ASC, but second two are seems should work... oddly...

Comment: Lowercase `asc` has solved the error - if you post an answer I will accept it.. Turns out the 2nd/3rd methods WERE working but another piece of code was obscuring the result.

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe my answer will be helpful for someone also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
database.model.clients.find({ myField: 'value' }).sort({ orgName: 'asc' })
```